# cURL works via command line but not in PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, xml-rpc

The following command works perfect in the command line:

```
c:\>curl -v -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><methodCall><methodName>create_account</methodName><params><param><value><struct><member><name>user</name><value><string>test</string></value></member><member><name>server</name><value><string>chat3.activengage.com</string></value></member><member><name>password</name><value><string>test</string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodCall>" http://localhost:4561
* About to connect() to localhost port 4561 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4561 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost:4561
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 428
>
* upload completely sent off: 428 out of 428 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 113
< Server: Erlang/Process-One
< Connection: close
<
<?xml version="1.0"?><methodResponse><params><param><value><int>0</int></value><
/param></params></methodResponse>* Closing connection #0
```

And in PHP using the code below:

```
public /*string*/ function registerUser(/*string*/$user,/*string*/$pass){
        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><methodCall><methodName>create_account</methodName><params><param><value><struct><member><name>user</name><value><string>test2</string></value></member><member><name>server</name><value><string>chat3.activengage.com</string></value></member><member><name>password</name><value><string>test</string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodCall>";
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:4561');
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        $content = curl_exec($handle);
        echo $xml;
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        print_r($httpCode);
        print_r($content);
        if(curl_errno($handle))
        {
         echo 'error:' . curl_error($handle);
        }
        curl_close($handle);
}
```

The result is a HTTP Status code 400. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE - The result of CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT**

```
string(99) "POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4561
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 400

"
```

Comment: The *only* difference I can see is that you reference the server by `localhost` at command line and `127.0.0.1` in the PHP code, and I'm just wondering if some kind of virtual hosting configuration is sticking it's nose in and breaking it. Other than the I can't see an obvious problem.

Comment: I get the same result using localhost in the php.

Comment: I thought you probably would, it was worth a shot. Can you add a `curl_setopt($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);` before calling `curl_exec()`, and show us the output of `var_dump(curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));` after it?

Comment: it works find on my machine using 'localhost' instead of 'http://127.0.0.1:4581' (by works fine i mean it brings me to the root document of my xampp server)

Comment: @dano That's because you haven't configured any `<VirtualHost>` containers, or you have properly configured the necessary `ServerAlias` directives to ensure that the right page is served. Apache virtual hosting is a complicated beast, and I don't think XAMPP is very well set up for using it IIRC.

Comment: @ashansky You content lengths are a bit odd but the PHP one does match so that's not going to be the problem. I suspect your server wants a `User-Agent:` header, try changing the header line to `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml', 'User-Agent: My-funky-user-agent'));`

Comment: @DaveRandom you were absolutely right! Adding that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Running a curl request from my browser based PHP script failed after I broke my etc/resolv.conf file.

I discovered this after visiting

[php5-curl error: couldn't resolve host](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lucky.openbsd.misc/yiooMaId4-c/SPUd75RzL3kJ)

After fixing the resolve.conf file as follows:
(note: 192.168.1.1 is my router address)

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Curl behaved as expected.

I Hope it helps you

Comment: Sheesh, I put the gogole DNS in first before internal DNS entries. So far this has broken Dreamweaver access and curl. Thanks for your post.