# Reasons why cURL would connect fine over command line, but not in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, connection, timeout

Recently I've started experiencing issues with a piece of code that has been stable for quite a while. It makes a connection to GameStop to retrieve a page there. Worked fine for years, but is now returning a timeout.

At first I assumed there was some sort of IP or user-agent blocking involved. However, I have spun up brand new machines on both DigitalOcean and Vultr, and both experience the same issue. Although, all the machines are able to use cURL via command line and retrieve the page fine.

Strangely, the code also work on my local development machine, which is a Windows box. So, not sure if there issue is related to PHP running on Linux?

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.gamestop.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); -explicitly use TLS v1.2

$html = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>' . var_export($error, true) . '</pre>'
     . '<pre>' . var_export($info, true) . '</pre>'
    . 'HTML: <textarea>' . $html . '</textarea>';

?>
```

The above code returns a timeout in any non-local environment I've tried to run it in. In the same environments, the page can be fetched with cURL via command line. I've found some similar questions posted, but most point towards an issue with SSL/TLS version. Have attempted to test this as well (see commented out line), but with same result.

Part of the issue is, I'm not sure there is a real way to debug a timeout coming from a server, as really anything could be causing it. The only real clue I've been going off is that it works on a Windows machine, and on command line in higher environments. Any help or insights would be appreciated!

Edit: Was also able to reproduce the issue on a Windows Server 2016 VM.

Comment: thers more ways to detect your a bot than IP and user agent

Comment: Which, I realize, however the fact that I can still fetch the page with cURL via command line makes me think it isn't an attempt to block, and more likely some sort of side effect of a change on their side.

Comment: There are 2 PHP ini files typically  (`php.ini` and `php-cli.ini` ), one for command line, one for http.  It's possible one has different settings then the other. even different extensions installed.  Without any error messages it's hard to say.  I found this out the hard way with timezones, on HTTP correct time on CLI wrong time, they had different timezones set.  It's not impossible you have one version of SSL for one and a different one for the other.

Comment: To clarify, when testing via command line, and seeing it work, I'm simply running: 

`curl -v https://www.gamestop.com/`

Not the actual PHP script/code.

Comment: or you could just not crawl a site that asks you not to.

Comment: tim, not sure why you are choosing to take time to be negative in comments, surely there are better uses of your time? Also, the site didn't 'ask me not to', there was no 403 Forbidden or message of any kind mentioning a block, and as I stated the page can still be fetched via cURL on command line.

Comment: Sounds like might be a DNS issue on the linux boxes youre using

Comment: try file_get_contents('https://www.gamestop.com'); If it doesnt work its the DNS settings on the server

Comment: Was just able to reproduce the issue on a Windows Server 2016 box as well. Although, I am kind of leaning towards the possibility of some DNS issue perhaps.

I've gone down that avenue a bit, by using gethostbyname in PHP, I see that the host name is resolving to an IP on the remote VM's. The IP is different than what I'm seeing locally. However, even when I update my HOSTS file on dev machine to the same IP as remote (to force it to resolve to same), it still works locally.

Comment: When I tested the reverse (forcing the IP that resolved locally on remote VM's), still the same timeout issue as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644757/7077417

Comment: I ended up using shell_exec to call cURL from PHP, then process the output.

Not as nice as using the wrapper, but for some reason it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely it's because curl-cli automatuically adds a user-agent header, and libcurl/php does not.

> some sort of IP or user-agent blocking involved. However, I have spun up brand new machines on both DigitalOcean and Vultr, and both experience the same issue

setting up VM's on DigitalOcean/Vultr will not automatically make libcurl add user-agent headers to your https requests. that can be done with:

```
curl_setop($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"curl/".(curl_version()["version"])); // User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
```

to mimic curl-cli's user-agent string, or something like

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36");
```

to pretend that you're a Google Chrome version 71, running on Windows 7 x64.

many websites (like, for example, Wikipedia.com ) blocks http requests lacking a User-Agent header.

Comment: I tried with standard user agents previously with no luck, but oddly enough it started working once I set it to just curl/version. Which matches the standard user agent applied by command line, as you mentioned. This explains why it worked on command line, but not in code until now.

Comment: @David is it possible that they block user-agents they detect as forged / false / lying? that would be intriguing

Comment: Could be, maybe they are OK with bots, as long as they clearly report as such? Pretty odd! I'm fine with that though, the reason I've ever used a 'fake/spoofed' user agent is to get a correctly formatted page. Sometimes if you use 'bot' or other unknown user agent, sites will return an old compatibility version of the site (thinking you are on some outdated browser).

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't really explain *why* this is occurring, I was able to get around the issue by using shell_exec in PHP to execute command line cURL directly, then retrieve/process the results.